# How to deploy cloud functions to different projects inside .firebaserc?

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-functions, firebase-tools

Is there a way to deploy functions to different firebase projects listed inside `.firebaserc` with a single command?

I have this sample `.firebaserc`

```
{
  "projects": {
    "default": "project1",
    "project2": "project2-abcd"
  }
}
```

When updating functions, I do:

```sh
firebase use default && firebase deploy && firebase use project2 && firebase deploy
```

If I have tons of projects, the command gets longer so I made a node script that automates deploying to all projects listed in `.firebaserc`:

```js
const { promisify } = require("util");

const exec = promisify(require("child_process").exec);
const readFile = promisify(require("fs").readFile);

const deploy = async () => {
  try {
    const data = await readFile("./.firebaserc", "utf-8");
    const projects = Object.keys(JSON.parse(data).projects);

    for (const proj of projects) {
      console.log(`Deploying functions to ${proj}...`);
      const { stdout, stderr } = await exec(
        `firebase use ${proj} && firebase deploy`
      );

      console.log("stdout:", stdout);
      console.log("stderr:", stderr);
    }
  } catch (e) {
    console.log(e);
  }
};

deploy();
```

which works but I'm trying to look for an alternative if there is one.

Answer (score 0):

Could you use the `--project` flag?

ex. `firebase deploy --project=project2`

See https://firebase.google.com/docs/cli#use_aliases .

> If you want to run a single command against the Firebase project that you've assigned the prod alias, then you can run, for example, firebase deploy --project=prod.

### Updated

Do you want to deploy all projects listed inside .firebaserc?

It may be possible to use like a following one-liner command.

ex.

`cat .firebaserc | jq '.projects | keys | .[]' | xargs -I {} firebase deploy --project={}`

See:

- [jq](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/)
- [xargs](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/xargs.1.html)

Comment: This only applies to a single project with prod alias.